# Lambdas function on multiple columns

Tags: pandas, lambda

I am trying to extract only number from multiple columns in my pandas data.frame.

I am able to do so one-by-one columns however I would like to perform this operation simultaneously to multiple columns

My reproduced example:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset('diamonds')


# Create columns one again

df['clarity2'] = df['clarity']
df.head()

df[['clarity', 'clarity2']].apply(lambda x: x.str.extract(r'(\d+)'))
```

Comment: Are you able to share a sample dataframe and expected output. There may be other ways to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a tuple

```
cols = ['clarity', 'clarity2']
tuple(df[col].str.extract(r'(\d+)') for col in cols)
```

If you want a list

```
cols = ['clarity', 'clarity2']
[df[col].str.extract(r'(\d+)') for col in cols]
```

adding them to the original data

```
df['digit1'], df['digit2'] = [df[col].str.extract(r'(\d+)') for col in cols]
```

Comment: And how to add these new columns to original Dataframe?

Comment: extended the answer to add the back to the original data